# In SwiftUI Is it possible for top level view to overlay a child's modal view

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to overlay the modal view of a child in the parent's ZStack doing the following:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var showGreen = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .onTapGesture {
                    showModal = true
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showModal) {
                    ModalView()
                        .environmentObject(viewModel)
                }
            if viewModel.showGreen {
                Color.green
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            viewModel.showGreen = true
        }
    }
}
```

Using this setup, is there anyway in the parent (ContentView in this case) to show a view that not only covers it's children but also the modally presented view's of it's children?

I know there are ways to do this by overlaying on the children themselves but that is not what I am after.

Comment: With UIKit you can present over current context. You would have to use a UIViewController representable to get it working in SwiftUI

Comment: representable not an option for my use case.  is there a way to achieve this with SwiftUI?

Comment: I don’t think so, you can find some workarounds in SO if you search for how to implement a toast in SwiftUI but I don’t think there is a pure SwiftUI way.

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to cover it inside ModalView**

```
struct ModalView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            if viewModel.showGreen {
                Color.green
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            viewModel.showGreen = true
        }
    }
}
```

**Another hack is to present one more modal view**

```
ModalView()
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $viewModel.showGreen) {
        Color.green
    }
    .environmentObject(viewModel)
```

**If you really need to build your cover outside of ModalView, pass it as a parameter**

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showGreen = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var showModal = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .onTapGesture {
                    showModal = true
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showModal) {
                    ModalView(content: {
                        if viewModel.showGreen {
                            Color.green
                        }
                    })
                        .environmentObject(viewModel)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView<Content: View>: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            content()
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            viewModel.showGreen = true
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: One more way without modifying ModalView**

```
ModalView()
    .overlay(content: {
        if viewModel.showGreen {
            Color.green
        }
    })
    .environmentObject(viewModel)
```

Comment: The op says they don’t want this at the end of their post.